# Show week 53 as yearweek in Python

Tags: python

Currently the results are showing year+week from the last 10 weeks. Like 201604 as the first 4 digits as the year and the last 2 as the week number. My problem is that it does not show week 53 (starts on Monday 28 December 2015 and ends on 3 January 2016).

Is there a way to show week 53 in the results?

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from datetime import date

yearweekArray = []
today = date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()
start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=weekday, weeks=10)
startOfWeek = today - start_delta

for i in range(0,10):
    yearweek = startOfWeek + timedelta(weeks=i)
    curDate = time.strptime(str(yearweek), "%Y-%m-%d")
    yearweekArray.append(time.strftime("%Y%W", curDate))
print yearweekArray
```

**EDIT:
Found an answer myself. See accepted answer below for the answer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to make it work.

This gives the exact same results as my original question's output but now with week 53 included and with a leading 0 to all weeks that have less then 2 digits.

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from datetime import date

yearweekArray = []
today = date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()
start_delta = datetime.timedelta(days=weekday, weeks=10)
startOfWeek = today - start_delta

for i in range(0,10):
    yearweek = startOfWeek + timedelta(weeks=i)
    curDate = time.strptime(str(yearweek), "%Y-%m-%d")
    curYear = int(time.strftime("%Y", curDate))
    curMonth = int(time.strftime("%m", curDate))
    curDay = int(time.strftime("%d", curDate))
    weekNum = "%02d" % (datetime.date(curYear, curMonth, curDay).isocalendar()[1],)
    yearweekArray.append(str(curYear) + str(weekNum))
print yearweekArray
```

The key here is to use isocalendar in place of trying to convert it with time.strftime("%Y%W", curDate)

**Output:**

```
['201552', '201553', '201601', '201602', '201603', '201604', '201605', '201606', '201607', '201608']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you use `time` module when it is unneeded, `datetime.date` has a `strftime` method.

Next, there is no week 53 in 2015! At least when you follow the Python convention:

> %W: Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. **All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0**.

(emphasize mine)

That means that Mon 6 Jan 2015 belongs to week 1 and Thu 1 Jan 2015 belong to week 0. As a result, Mon 21 Dec 2015 belongs to week 51 and Mon 28 Dec 2015 belongs to week 52.

Your results are correct.

Comment: http://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2015, I know that it belongs to week 0 when I convert it as %W. But is there a way to make week 0 to be shown as week 53

Comment: I noticed that "print datetime.date(2015, 12, 28).isocalendar()[1]" does returns week number 53. Is there an answer with this?